Why is my (working) code (which makes an interactive plot) not working anymore when putting it inside a function?
I made an interactive plot with python using matplotlib and I want to call it by putting it inside a function.
Everything works until I put my whole code inside the function make_plot(). Running the code without the make_plot() function gives me exactly what I want. Why is it not working anymore when inside another function (I just lose the interactive functionality)?
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import numpy as np

def make_plot():
    def button_clicked(event):
        global line_plotted
        if line_plotted:
            ax1.lines[1].remove()
            line_plotted = False
        else:
            ax1.plot(line[0], line[1], color='r', linestyle='--')
            line_plotted = True
        fig.canvas.draw()
            
    
    plt.ion()
    
    x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 500)
    y = np.sin(x)
    line = [0, 4 * np.pi], [1, 1]
    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot()
    ax1.plot(x,y)
    ax1.plot(line[0], line[1], color='r', linestyle='--')
    line_plotted = True
    
    button_ax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
    button = Button(button_ax, 'Show red line')
    button.on_clicked(button_clicked)
    
    
    
    plt.show()

make_plot()

I tried putting the button_clicked(event) function outside the make_plot() function but it didn't help.

The line global line_plotted suggests there's more code you don't show us. Supposedly, the problem is global variables being changed in your function. Please [edit] and share a [mre].

what is Button? is it from matplotlib.widgets? Please include the imports so we know which libraries are you using.

What solved my specific problem is to change global -> nonlocal and adding the line "x = input()" below "plt.show()".
This gives me the wanted result when I run the program from the terminal (on mac, just typing "python ").
But when I run the code directly from spyder, it still doesn't work. It would now just interest me why it is working from terminal but not from spyder.

It now feels as it wasn't done properly. Especially to use the input() command just to keep the function on hold seems like a "cheap trick"...

If you have another question, ask another question. Your original question said nothing about spyder so you cannot expect to get answers on spyder. And your new question may already have been answered; use this site's search.

Yeah well technically my original question wasn't answered...
Why do I lose the interactive functionality when putting my code inside a function?

global line_plotted

-->
nonlocal line_plotted

After you move all code inside a function, line_plotted doesn't live in global level, nonlocal keyword is used to reference a variable in the nearest scope.
Edit: full code
run in pycharm and spyder are all interactive -- click button .
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import numpy as np

matplotlib.use("TkAgg")


def make_plot():
    def button_clicked(event):
        nonlocal line_plotted
        if line_plotted:
            ax1.lines[1].remove()
            line_plotted = False
        else:
            ax1.plot(line[0], line[1], color="r", linestyle="--")
            line_plotted = True
        fig.canvas.draw()

    plt.ion()

    x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 500)
    y = np.sin(x)
    line = [0, 4 * np.pi], [1, 1]

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot()
    ax1.plot(x, y)
    ax1.plot(line[0], line[1], color="r", linestyle="--")
    line_plotted = True

    button_ax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
    button = Button(button_ax, "Show red line")
    button.on_clicked(button_clicked)

    plt.show(block=True)


make_plot()


The plot is still not interactive when making this change.

I test the full code , run in pycharm and spyder. Some differences with your origin code.

Yes, this is it. matplotlib.use("TkAgg") is not necessary in my case, but block=True inside plt.show() makes it work as needed. Thank you!
